# Keep getting error once inserting data to sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Once i opened my application it prompt me Unfortunately, database has stopped

```
public class Databasetest extends Activity {

private CommentDataSource datasource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_databasetest);


    datasource = new CommentDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();
    }
}
```

Below is the error I get can someone tell me what does it mean?..

```
(1) near "studentinfo_db": syntax error
```

This is my DataCommentSource :

```
 public class CommentDataSource {


  private SQLiteDatabase db;
  private MySQLiteHelper dbHlp;
  private String[] allColumns = { StudentInfo.COL_ROW_ID,
      StudentInfo.COL_STUDENT_NAME };

  public CommentDataSource(Context context) {
dbHlp = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
  }

  public void open() throws SQLException {
db= dbHlp.getWritableDatabase();
  }

  public void close() {
dbHlp.close();
  }
}
```

This is my MySQLiteHelper:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "studentsresult.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(StudentInfo.SQL_TABLE_NAME);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + StudentInfo.SQL_TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
  }
}
```

Above i had uploaded my source code.

Comment: can you share the code for this class `CommentDataSource`

Comment: Need more code to understand your problem.

Comment: post ur query which is error thrown on line(studentinfo_db)

Comment: I think error in query statement

Answer (score 1):

Modify the onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database){} as follows

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ StudentInfo.SQL_TABLE_NAME + "(" + 
                        StudentInfo.COL_ROW_ID + " INT PRIMARY KEY," +
                        StudentInfo.COL_STUDENT_NAME+ " TEXT)" );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table in on create like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+StudentInfo.SQL_TABLE_NAME);
}
```